# Fail to connect to web service server

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, jax-ws

I have an application running on JBoss 4.2.3 and Java 6, hosted on myApp.com.br. I'm developing a new web service client in this app, which have to access the server through a secure connection (HTTPS) using JAX to create a SOAP message.

I am sure that the message (XML) is succesfully created and addressed, but when it tries to connect, after 3 attempts, it throws an *SSLHandshakeException*. Below the excerpt of the log of the connections attempts:

```
13:55:41,014 INFO  [STDOUT] %% No cached client session
13:55:41,014 INFO  [STDOUT] *** ClientHello, TLSv1
13:55:41,015 INFO  [STDOUT] RandomCookie:  
13:55:41,015 INFO  [STDOUT] GMT: 1465512205 
13:55:41,015 INFO  [STDOUT] bytes = { 
13:55:41,015 INFO  [STDOUT] 89 AND LOTS OF OTHER NUMBERS WHICH I REMOVED FOR THE SAKE OF BREVITY
13:55:41,027 INFO  [STDOUT]  }
13:55:41,027 INFO  [STDOUT] Session ID:  
13:55:41,027 INFO  [STDOUT] {}
13:55:41,028 INFO  [STDOUT] Cipher Suites: [SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA]
13:55:41,028 INFO  [STDOUT] Compression Methods:  { 
13:55:41,028 INFO  [STDOUT] 0
13:55:41,028 INFO  [STDOUT]  }
13:55:41,029 INFO  [STDOUT] ***
13:55:41,029 INFO  [STDOUT] http-myApp.com.br%2F10.54.252.21-28080-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 73
13:55:41,029 INFO  [STDOUT] http-myApp.com.br%2F10.54.252.21-28080-1, WRITE: SSLv2 client hello message, length = 98
13:55:41,056 INFO  [STDOUT] http-myApp.com.br%2F10.54.252.21-28080-1, received EOFException: error
13:55:41,057 INFO  [STDOUT] http-myApp.com.br%2F10.54.252.21-28080-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
13:55:41,058 INFO  [STDOUT] http-myApp.com.br%2F10.54.252.21-28080-1
13:55:41,058 INFO  [STDOUT] , SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  
13:55:41,058 INFO  [STDOUT] fatal, 
13:55:41,059 INFO  [STDOUT] description = handshake_failure
13:55:41,059 INFO  [STDOUT] http-myApp.com.br%2F10.54.252.21-28080-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
13:55:41,060 INFO  [STDOUT] http-myApp.com.br%2F10.54.252.21-28080-1, called closeSocket()
13:55:41,060 INFO  [STDOUT] http-myApp.com.br%2F10.54.252.21-28080-1, called close()
13:55:41,060 INFO  [STDOUT] http-myApp.com.br%2F10.54.252.21-28080-1, called closeInternal(true)
13:55:41,088 INFO  [STDOUT] http-myApp.com.br%2F10.54.252.21-28080-1, setSoTimeout(0) called
```

And here are the throwed exceptions:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:808)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1112)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1139)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1123)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:904)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1026)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:373)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseMessage(HttpURLConnection.java:439)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseMessage(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:362)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.useHttpURLConnection(HTTPClientInvoker.java:340)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.transport(HTTPClientInvoker.java:137)
    at org.jboss.remoting.MicroRemoteClientInvoker.invoke(MicroRemoteClientInvoker.java:122)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:1634)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:548)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.client.HTTPRemotingConnection.invoke(HTTPRemotingConnection.java:233)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.client.SOAPProtocolConnectionHTTP.invoke(SOAPProtocolConnectionHTTP.java:73)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.CommonClient.invoke(CommonClient.java:339)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:302)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:172)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:152)
    at $Proxy691.solicitarProtocoloOperation(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.myApp.foundation.protocolmanager.service.ProtocolManagerBean.processMessageFromERP(ProtocolManagerBean.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:112)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:166)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3InterceptorsInterceptor.invoke(EJB3InterceptorsInterceptor.java:63)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInCallerTx(TxPolicy.java:126)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:195)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.security.AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.asynchronous.AsynchronousInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessContainer.localInvoke(StatelessContainer.java:240)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessContainer.localInvoke(StatelessContainer.java:210)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessLocalProxy.invoke(StatelessLocalProxy.java:84)
    at $Proxy613.processMessageFromERP(Unknown Source)
    at com.myApp.foundation.protocolmanager.ws.v1_00_00.WsdProtocolManagerWS.requestProtocol(WsdProtocolManagerWS.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:112)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:166)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3InterceptorsInterceptor.invoke(EJB3InterceptorsInterceptor.java:63)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInOurTx(TxPolicy.java:79)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:191)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.security.AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.asynchronous.AsynchronousInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss42.InvocationHandlerEJB3.invoke(InvocationHandlerEJB3.java:103)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.server.ServiceEndpointInvoker.invoke(ServiceEndpointInvoker.java:221)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.processRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:466)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:284)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.doPost(RequestHandlerImpl.java:201)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:134)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.EndpointServlet.service(EndpointServlet.java:84)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:432)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:333)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:789)
    ... 112 more
```

Apparently, the SOAP message is being send by JBoss with an internal IP "**http-myApp.com.br%2F10.54.252.21-28080-1**", and I think that this is the problem, for I believe that the certificate provider bound the certificate with the URL "myApp.com.br" and the external IP which it represents. I tested on SoapUI the same web service and use the same certificate and it works.

Is my assumption right? If so, how can I set up the JBoss to send the SOAP message correctly? If not, any idea of what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. The server doesn't accept SSL protocol.

Using Wireshark I was able to compare the packages sent by SoapUI, which work, with JBoss, which doesn't, and track the problem. I found that the protocols used by the applications were different. SoapUI used **TLSv1** while JBoss used **SSLv2**. So I configured JBoss to use only **TLSv1** and then it works. For record only, on JBoss 4.2.3 this was configured on *run.bat* file, where I added the line below:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1
```

The strange thing is that the Java documentation says that the default protocol is TLSv1, on Java 6, and I haven't configured SSL anywhere, or, at least, I haven't found anything with such configuration. I still don't know why it used SSL, though it is working.